# Set time every day in ruby

Tags: ruby, time

I made something to test the time. This is the Code:

```
time1 = Time.new
puts time1.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                    # |
                    # V  Change here
t = Time.new(2017, 9, 8, 14, 30, 0)

dist = ((t - time1) /60 ).round
dist1 = dist/60
dist2 = dist
while dist2 > 60
  dist2 = dist2 -60
end
puts "just #{dist1} hours and #{dist2} min left."
```

but I don't know how I create a fixed time for every day. I need to change it every day. Got some tips for me?

Comment: I am a bit confuse about your question. You Say that You need to 'create a fixed time for every day' but then You Say You also need to 'change it every day'. So do You need it  fixed or not ?

Comment: Or are You trying to calculate the difference in hours and minutes between two dates? Your english is a bit rough to understand to be honest.

Comment: at the moment i need to change it every day but i want it to always tell me how much time is left till the next time when its 2 pm. sry about my english ^^* im working on it

Answer (score 0):

```
t = DateTime.parse("14:30").to_time
```

The above would construct a time instance for today, 2:30PM.